# Unable to store values and pull one in another function

Tags: python

I have two functions - One thats meant to setup a simple game im making - And another thats the actual game - Code's not pretty but currently I'm throwing an error where the actual game cannot call a variable because its undefined.

The first function

```py
def gamestart():
    global numbertoguess
    currentplayer = turnorder
    print("Player {}, Youre up!".format(currentplayer+1))
    print("Rolling...")
    numbertoguess = random.randint(0,maxdice+1)
    time.sleep(3)
    game()
```

The game

```
def game():
    global probability, leftguesses, playerguesses, numbertoguess
    playerguesses = []
    leftguesses = maxdice - len(playerguesses)
    print("Alright. What do you think the number is? Player {}?".format(turnorder+1))
    probability = 1 / leftguesses
    print("Chance to get it correct... {}%".format(round(probability, 2)))
    playeranswer = int(input("> "))
    if playeranswer != numbertoguess:
        print("No not quite... Correct.")
        playerguesses.append(playeranswer)
        turninc()
    elif playeranswer in playerguesses:
        print("You already guessed that number, Player {}".format(turnorder+1))
        turninc()
    elif playeranswer == numbertoguess:
        print("You guessed the number, Player {}! Good work!".format(turnorder+1))
        menu()
```

`if playeranswer != numbertoguess:` is where the error is first thrown.

Comment: show us the actual error

Comment: This works fine for me (having added `import random, time; turnorder=0;maxdice=3;turninc=lambda: None; menu=lambda: None` so that all functions and global variables are defined) and calling `gamestart()` to start the game. If you call `game()` first then `numbertoguess` is not defined so it will raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is bad coding to use global variables like that. I am not really sure why you would have something in a different function if you still are going to use globals.

I am no pro at Python,but my solution would be to have game take that value as an argument.

```
def gamestart():
    currentplayer = turnorder
    print("Player {}, Youre  up!".format(currentplayer+1))
    print("Rolling...")
    numbertoguess = random.randint(0,maxdice+1)
    time.sleep(3)
    game(numbertoguess)


def game(num):
    .
    .
    if playeranswer != num:
```

Edit:

Also, the problem in your code could be that you have two global numbertoguess. Isin't the idea with global to only initialize it once, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your globals are all over the place. Consider this code:

```
import random


class GuessTheNumberGame:
    def __init__(self, max_num: int) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        
        self.max_num = max_num
        self.number_to_guess = random.randint(1, self.max_num)
        self.guessed_numbers: list[int] = []
        self.is_playing = True
        self.guesses = 0
        
    def game(self) -> None:
        print(f"Guess a number between 1 and {self.max_num}: ")
        while self.is_playing:
            player_choice = int(input('Your guess: '))
            self.check_guess(player_choice)
            self.guessed_numbers.append(player_choice)
        print(f"You guessed the number in {self.guesses} guesses!")
            
    def check_guess(self, player_choice: int) -> None:
        self.guesses += 1
        if player_choice in self.guessed_numbers:
            print('You already guessed that number!')
        else:
            if player_choice == self.number_to_guess:
                print("You guessed the number!")
                self.is_playing = False
            elif player_choice > self.number_to_guess:
                print("Your guess is too high!")
            else:
                print("Your guess is too low!")


def main() -> None:
    max_num = int(input("Enter the maximum number: "))
    game = GuessTheNumberGame(max_num)
    game.game()
    
main()
```

A simple class where you declare your variables on top. Everything you need.
`check_guess` method to do exactly what the name says and `game` method to control if you are still playing or not. Now please consider this as the beginning of your project where you can add your `propability` etc. You will only need a simple method to calculate that and then call it in the `game` method. It was easier to rewrite it for you as in your code you have `turnorder` and `maxdice` that haven't been declared but used. Also, you have `turninc()` and `menu()` but no code for this so I don't know what is happening there. Start it fresh, for future reference, avoid using globals.

As much as this does not answer your question, there was no way to answer it without actually rewriting pretty much everything. You've had no existing function called in your code and used undeclared variables pretty much everywhere. Also you've used `time.sleep` and `random` without import. Not sure if you just didn't copy imports or actually didn't import it.

`if playeranswer != numbertoguess:` is not first, your first one is `currentplayer = turnorder` than `maxdice` and so on. Think you didn't actually copy all of your code ;)

Also your `if elif` in `game` function is in wrong order. Your code will actually never check if number already been guessed. It will only check the right number and that one obviously won't be there, which is not what you actually wanted I think.